# Extremeley slow ethernet speeds with e1000e driver - Slackware64

Tags: networking

I have installed Slackware64 on a ThinkPad I had laying around, everything is great, except the network speed when using ethernet, i get at most speeds around 50KB/s, when using WiFi i get 2MB/s, I got the Intel e1000e driver during installation (auto) so i had nothing to do with selecting the driver. I don't know exactly what network card the ThinkPad has, but it should be one of these:

- Intel(R) 82566MC
- Intel(R) 82566MM
- Intel(R) PRO/1000 PL

And it seems that the e1000e driver is correct for these cards (?)
How do i troubleshoot this issue?

dmesg output (only network related stuff):

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.19 (root@z-mp.slackware.lan) (gcc (GCC) 11.2.0, GNU ld version 2.37-slack15) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 2 
[    0.376094] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    0.376461] IP idents hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.378385] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 2048 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.379570] TCP established hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.379797] TCP bind hash table entries: 32768 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.380145] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 32768 bind 32768)
[    0.380398] MPTCP token hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 98304 bytes, linear)
[    0.380532] UDP hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.380670] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.380835] NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
[    6.032325] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    6.032428] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    6.032701] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    6.196219] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T61p, model 6457BPG
[    6.196738] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    6.210006] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    6.335131] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:21:86:52:e2:96
[    6.335252] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    6.335382] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 6, PHY: 6, PBA No: 1008FF-0FF
[    6.430919] r592: driver successfully loaded
[    6.588644] r852: driver loaded successfully
[    6.739461] iwl4965: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi 4965 driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    6.739569] iwl4965: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[    6.739741] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    6.740057] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN, REV=0x4
[    6.789981] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x36, CALIB=0x5
[    6.790083] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 19 802.11a channels
[    6.905925] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 228.61.2.24
[    6.906440] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-4965-rs'
[    6.997414] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[    7.011395] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[   12.298270] NET: Registered PF_INET6 protocol family
[   12.314728] Segment Routing with IPv6
[   12.314732] RPL Segment Routing with IPv6
[   12.314747] In-situ OAM (IOAM) with IPv6
[   25.331509] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   25.331674] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   26.306170] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   28.581493] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   86.122694] wlan0: authenticate with 7e:45:58:3e:89:fc
[   86.138421] wlan0: send auth to 7e:45:58:3e:89:fc (try 1/3)
[   86.145036] wlan0: authenticated
[   86.146073] wlan0: associate with 7e:45:58:3e:89:fc (try 1/3)
[   86.151193] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 7e:45:58:3e:89:fc (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
[   86.171400] wlan0: associated
[   86.171464] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 7e:45:58:3e:89:fc
[   86.210160] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  105.544152] wlan0: deauthenticating from 7e:45:58:3e:89:fc by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  125.315396] fuse: init (API version 7.34)
[ 1416.229394] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1416.231136] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
[ 1416.231148] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Error sending C_RXON: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[ 1416.231156] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Error setting new RXON (-5)
[ 1530.599207] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: NIC Link is Down
[ 1535.920415] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[ 1535.920575] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

ifconfig output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.152  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 00:21:86:52:e2:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 58571  bytes 41168159 (39.2 MiB)
        RX errors 21118  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 11996
        TX packets 31800  bytes 9629606 (9.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xfe200000-fe220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 35  bytes 2474 (2.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35  bytes 2474 (2.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ethtool eth0 output:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: on (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```